# Filter in a spark window by comparing a single row element with all rows of the window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose you have a dataframe as follows:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|    date_a|    date_b|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-19|
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-19|
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-26|
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-26|
|  2|2020-01-05|2020-01-08|
|  3|2020-01-08|2020-01-10|
|  3|2020-01-12|2020-01-10|
+---+----------+----------+
```

For each id, there are date_a and date_b values, in various combinations.

---

I'd like to filter entries, where for a single id, date_b's are outside of a certain set time range around all date_a's.

A visual interpretation for id = 1 looks like (horizontal is time axis):

|---x---| o |-o--x---|

, where x = date_a, o = date_b and |--- ---| indicates the time range (i.e. +- 5 days).
Thus, "o" (date_b) entries should be kept, that are within none of the date_a timeranges (here, the first "o").

---

**Example input/output:**

Input:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2020-01-10', '2020-01-19'), 
     (1, '2020-01-10', '2020-01-26'),
     (1, '2020-01-30', '2020-01-19'),
     (1, '2020-01-30', '2020-01-26'),    
     (2, '2020-01-05', '2020-01-08'),
     (3, '2020-01-08', '2020-01-10'),
     (3, '2020-01-12', '2020-01-10'),],
     ['id', 'date_a', 'date_b']
)

df = df.withColumn('date_a', F.to_date('date_a'))
df = df.withColumn('date_b', F.to_date('date_b'))
df = df.withColumn('diff', F.datediff(df.date_b, df.date_a))
df.orderBy('id', 'date_b').show()

+---+----------+----------+----+
| id|    date_a|    date_b|diff|
+---+----------+----------+----+
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-19| -11|
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-19|   9|
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-26|  -4|
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-26|  16|
|  2|2020-01-05|2020-01-08|   3|
|  3|2020-01-08|2020-01-10|   2|
|  3|2020-01-12|2020-01-10|  -2|
+---+----------+----------+----+
```

Within the same `id`, we want to get `date_b`'s where the `diff` is `>5 or <-6` for all rows with the same `date_b` (`date_b` is outside of the interval `[date_a - 6, date_b + 5]`).
I.e.:
For `id=1, date_b='2020-01-19'`, (11 > 5 | 11 < -6) & (9 > 5 | 9 < -6) -> entry is kept (True & True)
For `id=1, date_b='2020-01-26'`, (4 > 5 | 4 < -6) & (16 > 5 | 16 < -6) -> entry is discarded (False & True)
...

Expected output:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|    date_a|    date_b|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-19|
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-19|
+---+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the expected output looks like?

Comment: The output for id = 1 should look like in the 2nd code block (df_filtered = ... [(1, '2020-01-10', '2020-01-20'), (1, '2020-01-30', '2020-01-20'),] ...). For id = 2 / 3, date_b is within +-5 days, so it should not be contained in the filtered df.

Comment: can you explain how does window come into picture(since we are filtering in the window too as per expected output), thank you

Comment: Please update your question with a proper output table.. this helps simplify understanding

Comment: @anky Mhm. probably my terminology is wrong, I thought of the window as a subset of the data with a single id (e.g. where id=1), I just thought that one could probably use the window function to solve the problem. So within one of these "windows", we filter the rows based on the condition that for each row, date_b must not be contained in the time ranges of _all_ date_a rows inside the window.
Is there a general solution for filtering within a subset of the df (window), where one row of the window is compared against all other rows inside the window?

Comment: @0vbb understood,no window is fine(for my understanding) so date_b should compare all date_a (not only current row) inside a window is what you mean?

Comment: @anky yes, exactly!

Comment: 1 more question, what is the spark version?

Comment: @anky 2.4.5, 3 when it is out of beta :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible approach, you can try (*comments inline*):

```
w = Window.partitionBy("id","date_b").orderBy("id")
cond = (F.col("diff")>5) | (F.col("diff")<-6)

#check if condition is true and get sum over the window
sum_of_true_on_w = F.sum(cond.cast("Integer")).over(w) 

#get window size to compare with the sum , there might be a better way to get size
size_of_window = F.max(F.row_number().over(w)).over(w)

#filter where sum over the window is equal to size of window
(df.withColumn("Sum_bool",sum_of_true_on_w)
   .withColumn("Window_Size",size_of_window)
   .filter(F.col("Sum_bool")==F.col("Window_Size"))
   .drop("diff","Sum_bool","Window_Size")).show()

+---+----------+----------+
| id|    date_a|    date_b|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|2020-01-10|2020-01-19|
|  1|2020-01-30|2020-01-19|
+---+----------+----------+
```